# How to add values to sqlite database in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a Django model as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

And I want to add some data to `db.sqlite3` file.

I have simple function as follows:

```
def get_vehicles():
    try:
        fetched_vehicles = [.....]
        for vehicle in fetched_vehicles:
            n_vehicle = Vehicle()
            n_vehicle.reference = "123456",
            n_vehicle.make = "SKODA",
            n_vehicle.model = "Octavia SW",
            n_vehicle.save()


        return "Success"
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

And when I execute this function in the database I see tuples instead of values as on the photo:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: That is because you added tailing commas (wrapping the values in a singleton tuple). You should write `.reference = "123456"` so *without* a comma at the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So stupid fout. Thanks.